# How to write a CSV with non-standard quote characters in R?

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I have a data frame that contains a text field. The text has quotes in it, so I want to use `@` as a quote character instead of `"` or `'`.

The `write.table` and `write.csv` functions do not allow other quote characters.

Is there some other function that lets me use a different quote character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can disable quoting and then wrap your strings in `@` characters.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
    if(is.character(x) || is.factor(x))
        x <- sprintf("@%s@", x)
    x
})
write.csv(df, "file.csv", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

(And turn off row names while we're at it, since they'll just mess things up.)

Comment: I'd back up a copy of `df` in the case that the original `data.frame` should stay unchanged. Guess `df2<-df` and then your lines should be safer. +1.

Comment: Yes, I used a copy when using this function. This works. I just wish it were built in, similar to `read.csv()`